# Mac/Windows different formats for in_addr structure (IPv4 address)

Tags: c++, windows, macos, ip-address

I'm porting some Windows code to the Mac. I've come across some code using the type `in_addr` and found the documentation for the Windows implementation here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms738571%28v=vs.85%29.aspx

Specifically the problem I am having is that the code tries to access the `S_un` property of in_addr, which the compiler (CLang) complains doesn't exist. Looking at the definition for the Mac implementation I get this (in `usr/include/netinet/in.h`):

```
struct in_addr {
    in_addr_t s_addr;
};
```

...and `in_addr_t` is defined as follows (in `usr/include/sys/types.h`):

```
typedef __uint32_t      in_addr_t;
```

Does anyone know of a good workaround for this, or if there is a representation of IPv4 addresses on the Mac that is more closely tied to the Windows implementation?

Comment: what is it exactly that the code is accessing? because `S_un` is just a union. If it's accessing `S_un.S_addr` that's the same as just accessing `s_addr`. Else you need to extract the data yourself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See my comment. But also ... you can just implement the windows declaration in your code (just do not call it in_addr to avoid conflicts). You could do something like:

```
 typedef struct Win_in_addr {
   union {
     struct {
       __uint8_t s_b1,s_b2,s_b3,s_b4;
     } S_un_b;
     struct {
       __uint16_t s_w1,s_w2;
     } S_un_w;
     __uint32_t S_addr;
   } S_un;
 } Win_IN_ADDR, *Win_PIN_ADDR, *Win_LPIN_ADDR;
```

Note however that this is not portable and will only work as intended on little endian CPUs.

Comment: Thanks - yeah I thought I might need to do that. Thanks for the note about endianness as well, definitely worth keeping that in mind.

Comment: Just to clarify and settle my curiosity, are you suggesting use of this structure only if @benwad's code needs to access anything other than `S_addr`? As otherwise I'd have thought `#define S_un.S_addr S_addr` would do the trick. Regarding the comment about portability / little-endian, is that because you're assuming it's possible that the application might be trying to access various members, e.g. initially program S_addr and then later read s_b1? From the reading I've been doing, I get the impression that `S_addr` is, or should, be the only member used.